# Real time rendering and changing of 3D model in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, 3d

I have no knowledge of how one would  go about something like this, but, I want to include a spinning 3D model of a anatomic human figurine. However, the model needs to be slightly modified based on certain interactions in the app - essentially showing a heat-map or shaded areas on the 3D model.

I am writing the application in Dart/Flutter.

I'd really appreciate any advice for the direction I should follow and whether something like this may be feasible.